# Why there is no `shutdown` method for TcpListener and UdpSocket in Rust

Tags: rust

According to the documentation, `TcpListener` and `UdpSocket` will be automatically closed when the value is dropped/out of scrope. But why is there no `shutdown` method to let me manually close them?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html

Comment: You can manually `drop()` it. There isn't any reason why keeping around a handle to a closed socket should be possible.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `std::mem::drop` to drop a value early:

```rust
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:80")?;
// ...
drop(listener);
// ...
```

There is no `shutdown` method because it isn't needed. The existing ownership system is already good enough for keeping track of if a socket is usable, and there is nothing you can *do* with a closed socket anyways.

Comment: That not why there is no shutdown method on TcpListenr, see answer from iggy.

Answer (score 7):

You confuse [`TcpListener`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html) and [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html).

'shutdown' in TCP sockets has a technical meaning. Shutdown on the send side transmits a FIN to the remote.  Shutdown on the receive side means that any arriving data segments will get a RST response.  These definitions are only applicable to a TCP connection in data transfer state, not to listening sockets.

Comment: So what? Local resources, such as the open socket, still have to be cleaned up. I don't know where you picked up this "meaning", but in *nix systems it simply lets you to [shut down read/recv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) of the socket.

Comment: @Stargateur What does this have to do with what I wrote?

Comment: @Stargateur 5 words that completely change the meaning of original answer which has nothing to do with my original comment.

Comment: @Kaihaku - ever looked at what actually happens when you call shutdown() on a TCP socket under Unix?  Local kernel resources are cleaned up by a close(),, not shutdown().  Most layered APIs then make their shutdown methods call shutdown() on the socket, since doing otherwise would be surprising.   I confess, however, to not having noticed this was a Rust-specific question, about which I have no direct knowledge.

Comment: @Kaihaku - the 5 words do **not** change the intended meaning of my answer. They add a worthwhile clarification of my point.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually close a listener simply by explicitly dropping:

```rust
drop(listener);
```